# C# design view won't load graphical elements in winform

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I had three separate applications I created for a client that the client eventually asked be collected into a single screen from which they could launch whichever app they desired. To do this I basically created a new project with a simple form with three buttons that would then call the code for whichever sub-app was called and I copied the code from each project into the main one.

The application works, but for some reason something weird happened with the design files and they will no longer load in the designer view - that is, if I try to open them in design view I just see an empty form.

If I run the program, everything works exactly as it did before. The forms display as they were and there are no errors - but the client asked for a new button in a specific location and this leaves me having to manually edit the .Designer.cs files and moving around a dozen labels and buttons and textboxes to accommodate the new addition...

I am not sure what exactly went wrong. There are no errors and as I said, the program compiles and runs without a hitch. For some reason, the designer files are not collapsed under the form files but seem to lie outside it in the solution exporer:

[image]

I don't know if this is a clue or just an unrelated glitch.

I tried creating a new form from scratch and copying the code from the designer.cs file into the new forms' to try to see if it would load the data and let me edit it but it didn't work.

If there any way to force the designer to reload all it's elements from the Designer file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't edit the designer file directly. It's easy to mess things up. You should use the graphical editor. Don't know what you did but you messed something up in it. I would revert it and do the changes directly in the form editor.

Regarding your problem with the designer file not being under the form file,
in your project file you need to have that designer file marked as being dependent on the other one.

```
<Compile Include="Form1.cs">
  <SubType>Form</SubType>
</Compile>
<Compile Include="Form1.Designer.cs">
  <DependentUpon>Form1.cs</DependentUpon>    <---- HERE
</Compile>
```

This is probably missing.

Answer (score 0):

Great !
this indeed fix the issue

```
<Compile Include="Form1.Designer.cs">
  <DependentUpon>Form1.cs</DependentUpon>    <---- HERE
</Compile>
```

it can sometime happen when re-using / copy forms across project and manualy changing the namespace of the form Code and Designer